# Search and replace in file on windows using win_lineinfile

Tags: windows, ansible

`file.txt` with contents as follows:

```
userName    =    'ABCD'
password    =    'XYZ'
```

How to search and replace username and password on Windows using an Ansible playbook.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using ansible's win_lineinfile module as follows.

```
- name: Update file.txt
  win_lineinfile: 
    dest='c:\file.txt' backrefs=yes state=present
    regexp='^\{{ item.search_patttern }}\s*=\s*[\`\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\+\=\{\[\}\]\\\|\:\;\"\'\<\,\>\.\?\/\w]*' 
    line="{{ item.replacement }}" 
  with_items:
    - { search_patttern: "username", replacement: "userName    =    \'NewUser\'" }
    - { search_patttern: "password", replacement: "password    =    \'NewPassword\'" }
```